# How to compare only output part in html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a plan to create an app for JavaScript test. In here I will give a question for creating a program, for example, **show the text "HTML Code Play" in alert box?** The user will do the coding, and they can use any name for the functions, variable, etc.

I want to check the output, where the output show the alert box "HTML Code Play".

**User Code**

```
<script>
function showalert()
{
 alert("HTML Code Play");
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Show Alert" onclick="showalert();">
```

**Compare with the following code(My code)**

```
<button onclick="alertbox();">Show Alert</button>

<script>
function alertbox()
{
 alert("HTML Code Play");
}
</script>
```

In the examples above, both produce the same output but the coding is different. 
When I check both codes,  I want the result **true**. Can I do it? Is it possible?

Comment: How they are different ?

Comment: How about a browser simulator? You could try CasperJS if yes.

Comment: I am using cordova for android app

Comment: I wonder if some sort of unit testing framework would help with this.

Comment: @Adyson It looks not helpful. Can you give a sample code using the above code?

Comment: @AsithRaj the reason I mentioned unit testing frameworks is because they usually involve ways of asserting that certain output has been achieved (given certain inputs). You're wanting to assert that the alert box is triggered, so I felt it might be similar. More generally, you're going to be asking people to write code with a certain specified output, so in theory you ought to be able to write an automated test for it. I've never used any JS testing frameworks myself, so it's up to you to research the specifics.

Comment: -1 I see nothing interesting in this example. If a call to a function come from an element then there is no difference where the function is declared.

Answer (score -1):

I found your question interesting, and created sample code using mocha and sinon.
(To exec this, you must install sinon.js modules by yourself.)
I published this code [here](http://hitokun-s.github.io/tech/test-user-code-on-browser.html) as working code.

Please regard 'code1','code2' blocks as user-implemented codes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>How to test user code on broweer</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.5.3/mocha.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.5.3/mocha.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../components/sinon/lib/sinon.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../components/sinon/lib/sinon/util/core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../components/sinon/lib/sinon/extend.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../components/sinon/lib/sinon/spy.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../components/sinon/lib/sinon/call.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>How to test user code on broweer</h1>
    <div id="mocha"></div>

    <div id="live-code-stage"></div>

    <template id="code1">
        <button onclick="alertbox();">Show Alert</button>
        <script>
            function alertbox() {
                alert("HTML Code Play");
            }
        </script>
    </template>
    <template id="code2">
        <script>
            function showalert() {
                alert("HTML Code Play");
            }
        </script>
        <input type="button" value="Show Alert" onclick="showalert();">
    </template>
</div>
<script>
    mocha.setup('bdd');

    $(function () {
        var assert = function (expr, msg) {
            if (!expr) throw new Error(msg || 'failed');
        };
        describe("implement 'show alert button' test", function () {
            before(function () {
                window.alert = sinon.spy();
            });
            it("window.alert must to be called with 'HTML Code Play'", function (done) {

                $("#live-code-stage").html($("#code1").html()); // testing code1

                $("button, input[type='button']").click();
                assert(window.alert.calledWith("HTML Code Play"));
                done();
            });
        });
        mocha.run();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Key Points

- You can mock 'window.alert' like this:
  `window.alert = sinon.spy();`
- And you can check if it(=alert) was called with correct argument like this:
  `assert(window.alert.calledWith("HTML Code Play"));`

If user-created code is wrong, mocha test will fail.
Introducing qunit may improve the test report appearance.

But this is just a sample. There must be many options to archive what you want.

Comment: It has nothing to OP.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Please explain more. I think the main purpose of questioner is, 'to create an app for JavaScript test' and 'check if user code is correct( "can" alert in real environment)'.

Comment: OP said nothing about the purpose of the code provided. So you cannot answer the question which is not set. Your code may be good but it is irrelevant to OP.

Comment: @hitokun_s Can you create a post in jsfiddle.net,